# Copying entire dir using SFTP

Tags: scp, sftp

In **sftp**,
`put *` or `get *` do not get the hidden files or directories inside a `dir`.

What to do if I want to use sftp to copy entire dir, along with the subdirs that are **hidden**?

For example, a `.git` directory inside the directory.
I do not require the `scp` commands. How to do that in a `sftp` shell?

Comment: this is *not* a duplicate. This question is concerned with hidden files. The linked question does not say anything about hidden files. Additionally this is the number one google-hit for "sftp hidden files"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use -r switch

```
sftp> get -r folder/
```

Comment: this actually does copy hidden files! You should emphasize that the key to copying hidden files ist the slash "/" at the end!